# fopen() not opening CSV in browser

Tags: php, csv, fopen

I have a script that runs on a cron job on a linux server hosted on Godaddy. It works fine. However, when I try to run that script from a browser, `fopen()` returns `false`.

I have it echoing out the URL being used to ensure that my variables are coming in properly and they are. I can copy/paste them from the browser window into the address bar and I receive the file I should.

Can someone point me in the direction as to why these few lines of code are working when run as a cron job but not in the browser?

```
$URL="http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/".$date['yymmdd']."_rpts_".$type.".csv";

echo $URL."<br />";

if(@$csvHandle=fopen($URL,'r')){
```

Comment: Check files permissions

Comment: No issue there, the cron job is still running with no errors on the same files.

Answer (score 0):

Once I cranked up the php error reporting, `allow_url_fopen` was set to off. Once it was turned on, everything worked fine. Wish I had thought of just checking the errors earlier. But that's why we walk away, get some coffee, and come back.